# flutter : how to groupBy two or more fields?

Tags: flutter

how can I use `groupBy` function which is in `collection.dart` to group items by two fields and return a model class with them  **not** one field like `int`?

If I group by one field, It works fine and there is no problem:

```
 Map<int, List<FooterItem>> _getGroups(List<FooterItem> items) {
    return groupBy(items, (FooterItem i) {
      return  i.groupId;
    });
  }
```

But when I wan to return a model class from result ,`groupBy` is not grouping values .
here I have a list of `FooterItem` which has It's group data and how can I use `groupBy` to group a `List<FooterItem>`  by  `groupId` and `titleGroup` and return  FooterGroup not int :

```
class FooterItem {
  final int id;//item id
  final int groupId;
  final String title;//item title
  final String titleGroup;
...
}

Map<FooterGroup, List<FooterItem>> _getGroups(List<FooterItem> items) {
    return groupBy(items, (FooterItem i) {
      return FooterGroup(id: i.groupId, title: i.titleGroup);
    });
  }
```

Comment: @pskink thanks for hashCode idea. I could solve the problem by extending `Equatble` which simplifies equality comparisons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve problem by extending `Equatable` in the model class which I wanted to use as grouped values and overriding props  :

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
class FooterGroup extends Equatable{
  final int id;
  final String title;

  FooterGroup({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
  });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [id,title];
}
```

so duplicate values of Groups where not seen any more. so

```
Map<FooterGroup, List<FooterItem>> _getGroups(List<FooterItem> items) {
    return groupBy(items, (FooterItem i) {
      return FooterGroup(id: i.groupId, title: i.titleGroup);
    });
  }
```

works fine now.

Comment: yep, `Equatable` is a nice helper class

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to achieve this:

```
groupBy(footers, (FooterItem f) {
  return '${f.groupId}+${f.titleGroup}';
});
```

Source: https://coflutter.com/dart-how-to-group-items-in-a-list/